# List out all the records when the results are filtered by GroupBy

Tags: sql, ms-access

My requirement is to verify whether the Total or Sum of `Column2` (group by `Column1`) should be equal to `Column3` (group by `Column1`) using `MS Access`.

With example,
Total of `DebitAmount` (group by `AccountNumber`) should be equal to `BillAmount` (for the same account number). i.e., Total of `DebitAmount` (or `SUM(DebitAmount)`) for AccountNumber='129610896' should be equal to 30000

likewise Total of `DebitAmount` (or `SUM(DebitAmount)`) for AccountNumber='184046309' should be equal to 19000

```
AccountNumber   Code    DebitAmount BillAmount
129610896       B2B001  25000   30000
129610896       B2B032  5000    30000
184046309       B2B001  15830   19000
184046309       B2B032  3170    19000
```

I have written a query as below

```
SELECT AccountNumber, BillAmount, iif ((Sum(DebitAmount) - BillAmount) = 0,1,0) as IsVerify 
FROM Master_Table GROUP BY AccountNumber,BillAmount 

AccountNumber   BillAmount  IsVerify
129610896       30000       1
184046309       19000       1
```

The result only displays the records group by account number. If I have 50 records, it displays only 20 as I group by account number.

But I want all the records to be displayed, IsVerify column should display the value '1' if the debit amount is equal to bill amount. If I include the column 'Code' in the query, it displays all the records, but the result displayed is invalid.

```
SELECT Code,AccountNumber, BillAmount, iif ((Sum(DebitAmount) - BillAmount) = 0,1,0) as IsVerify FROM Master_Table GROUP BY Code,AccountNumber,BillAmount
```

So how could I write the query to display all the records with the verification flag displayed as shown below.

```
AccountNumber   GLCode  DebitAmount BillAmount  IsVerify
129610896       GLB2B001    25000   30000       1
129610896       GLB2B032    5000    30000       1
184046309       GLB2B001    15830   19000       1
184046309       GLB2B032    3170    19000       1
```

The tables are not displayed correctly. So please refer the link
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/list-out-all-the-records-when-the-results-are/c217b32a-b869-46ce-bb88-a0f98f21708f?tm=1405351469299

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tm.*,
    IIF(
        (
            SELECT Sum(t.DebitAmount) 
            FROM Master_Table t
            WHERE t.AccountNumber = tm.AccountNumber
        ) = tm.BillAmount, 1, 0
    )
    as IsVerify 
FROM Master_Table tm
```

Excuse me if there are some minor errors because i work on mysql and t-sql. But logic is correct.

Comment: Hi All,

Thanks a lot for your answer. unfortunately it doesn't work.

But I have simplified the query as 

IIf(AccountNumber Not In 
(Select AccountNumber from 
(SELECT AccountNumber, iif (((CDBL((Sum(DebitAmount)- CDBL(BillAmount)) =0),1,0) AS IsVerify FROM Master_Table GROUP BY AccountNumber, BillAmount) where IsVerify = 0),1,0) as ANumber_SumBillAmountCheck

It works fine :)

Best regards
Basha

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there! :)  Try this one:

```
SELECT     mt.AccountNumber, mt.GLCode, mt.DebitAmount, mt.BillAmount, IIf(t1.SumOfDebitAmount - mt.BillAmount = 0,1,0) AS IsVerify
FROM       Master_Table AS mt INNER JOIN
           (SELECT AccountNumber, Sum(DebitAmount) AS SumOfDebitAmount
            FROM Master_Table
            GROUP BY AccountNumber) AS t1
           ON mt.AccountNumber = t1.AccountNumber
ORDER BY   mt.AccountNumber, mt.GLCode;
```

We get the DebitAmount totals within a derived table and then JOIN on account number.  If the total of the DebitAmount minus the BillAmount is 0, then the rows which represent the DebitAmounts are verified.  Note there was an issue with the statement:

```
IIf(t1.SumOfDebitAmount = mt.BillAmount,1,0)
```

It kept showing #Error.  Not sure why, really, but I couldn't do it that way.  Anyway, this should work for you.